# Регулярные выражения поиск числа после определенного слова

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка, в которой я хочу найти первое число (число целое, т.е. без десятичной точки) после заданного слова `Ultimate Question`.
Как сделать это при помощи регулярных выражений? Количество символов после  Ultimate Question может быть любое.

```
import re    

s1 = "Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything (42)"
print re.search('(Ultimate Question)(.)*(\d+)', s1).groups() # вывод('Ultimate Question', '4', '2')
```

Как получить число `42` стоящее после слова `Ultimate Question`?

Comment: Первое число после этого слова? Или первое число в скобках? А оно может быть дробным?

Comment: Да, первое число после этого слова

Comment: @nick_gabpe, число может быть с десятичной точкой?

Comment: @MaxU спасибо, нет не может.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
In [135]: re.search('Ultimate Question.*?(\d+)', s1).group(1)
Out[135]: '42'
```